# Karate framework - API hits successfully in Insomnia but not in Openshift v4 pod

Tags: karate

Using karate framework I am trying to hit an API deployed in Openshift v4 pod. Using the Insomnia tool I can hit the same and is getting success response but with karate unable to hit the same and in logs of the pod I have checked the request is not reaching at all.

### karate script

```
* url "https://apihost/path"
    * header Content-Type = 'application/json'
    * header Accept = 'application/json'
    * configure ssl = true

Scenario: Test API call
    Given path 'xyz/somvevalue'
    And request {}
    And header someheaderkey1 = 'someheadervalue1'
    And header someheaderkey2 = 'someheadervalue2'
    When method Post
    Then status 200
    And print "Response is --> ", response
```

Response
503
Application is not available . The application is currently not serving requests at this endpoint. It may not have been started or is still starting.

The host exists, but doesn't have a matching path.
Check if the URL path was typed correctly and that the route was created using the desired path.
Route and path matches, but all pods are down.
Make sure that the resources exposed by this route (pods, services, deployment configs, etc) have at least one pod running.

Expecting success response with response status 200 OK

Comment: you are certainly missing some header or the JSON is not formed as the server is expecting. so you are on your own, and a good way to resolve this is work with your server-side team. that said, if you can update your question with the cURL command (which you may be able to export from insomnia) that can provide some clues, but otherwise, without others being able to see your server, no one can help, sorry

Comment: Hi  Peter, Thanks as  requested please find curl request --> curl --request POST \
  --url https://apihost/path \
  --header 'X-header1: {"identifiers":[{"id":"xxxxxxxxxx","sourceSystem":"customerId"}]}' \
  --header 'X-header2: {"UID":"xxxxxxxxx","BUID":"xxxxxxxxx","channel":{"CHN":"x"},"DVID":"xxxxx","role":"xxxxxx"}'.

Comment: Also as I mention earlier that the request is  not reaching to the server hence I  am not sure if server side team can be of much help here   but  still  will check with team. Please note for Insomnia request is reaching to server  and we can see logs.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the cURL you provided, this is all I can make out:

```
* url 'apihost/path'
* header X-header1 = '{\"identifiers\":[{\"id\":\"xxxxxxxxxx\",\"sourceSystem\":\"customerId\"}]}'
* header X-header2 = '{\"UID\":\"xxxxxxxxx\",\"BUID\":\"xxxxxxxxx\",\"channel\":{\"CHN\":\"x\"},\"DVID\":\"xxxxx\",\"role\":\"xxxxxx\"}'
* method post
```

One more thing to try is to add `* request ''` to ensure it is "empty" and not `{}`

If you are using variables, [convert them to strings](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#type-conversion) when using as header values. For example:

```
* header someheaderkey1 = karate.toJson(someheadervalue1)
```

Else I have no suggestions. It sure looks like a weird API.